# How to create a jagged border in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, border

I want to create a jagged border around a container (see image below). Anyones know how to do that ?[Jagged border example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIZvJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a perfect solution.
I use a ClipPath and add a CustomClipper:

```dart
class HorizontalJaggedBorderClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    double y = 0;
    double x = size.width;
    double increment = size.height / 6;
    double delta = size.height * 0.15;

    while (y < size.height) {
      y += increment;
      x = (x == size.width) ? size.width - delta : size.width;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    x = 0;
    while (y > 0) {
      x = (x == 0) ? delta : 0;
      y -= increment;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return oldClipper != this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that makes it simple: [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border)

Example:

```
DottedBorder(
    color: Colors.black,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 148),
)
```

Comment: I mean a jagged border in my image, not dash border around the image